# can't connect between web-panel and game-server at same machine

Tags: linux, centos, localhost, mysql

I am using sourceban(web game panel) and running game-server at the same machine 
but when i try to connect from webpanel to gameserver it give me Failed to connect

this is my mysqld config

```
    [mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

this is my mysqld log :

```
140607 01:03:03 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140607 01:03:05 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140607 1:03:05 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
140607 1:03:05 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140607 1:03:05 InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
140607 1:03:05 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140607 1:03:05 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.73' socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' port: 3306 Source distribution
140607 01:039 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
140607 01:03:50 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
```

i am using linux
thanks

Comment: Ah! you're talking about Valve's source engine (game-server) and Sourcebans is a plugin for it with a PHP web interface. Technical support for products is **way** off-topic for Stack Overflow, so expect this question to be closed by someone.

Comment: However, you're in a bit a luck since I've run Source myself (a while ago), and I'm familiar enough with PHP (which Sourcebans is written in) and MySQL. If you can figure out how to private message me, I'll try to help figure it out

Comment: ok Thanks i just fixed the error that was at game server log but now there is no log at the game server but the problem continue..